# How to reduce google app engine pricing for my static website

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am deploying my website on google app engine with nodejs i read their docs that they provide **28 instance hours free per day**, currently we only have a few limited static data so i thought my website pricing will be under the quota, but as by default when we deploy an app on app engine they provide you two instances so now my usage per day will be 48 hours and as **each instance hour is priced as 0.05 per day** so finally they are going to charge me **((48 - 28)*0.05) = $1 per day**, can anyone please tell me how can i make my app free as i don't think they should charge me right now as there is nothing on my website. I also tried to use min_pending_latency as well as max_idle_instances but i am getting the error

> VM-based automatic scaling should NOT have the following parameter(s): [min_pending_latency, max_idle_instaces

Comment: One has to ask, if it is truly a static web site, then why is nodejs in the mix ?

Comment: because i am going to add functionality some time later but right now all my part is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like this in the app.yaml:

```
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 20
  cool_down_period_sec: 30
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
```

Use the [front end cache](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching) for your static data, this should make request be answered without hitting your instances